# Pre-load image before using it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using an image that needs to change when you click on it and to do that I'm using a JavaScript onclick. There a brief "flick" the first time I do it while it load the image but this only happens the first time. Is there a way to preload the second image so the change it as smooth the first time as it is all the others?

Answer (score 2):

Preloading images is a great way to improve the user experience. You have 3 Ways to Preload Images with CSS, JavaScript, or Ajax:

#### Method 1: Preloading with CSS and JavaScript

```css
#preload-01 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-01.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
#preload-02 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-02.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
#preload-03 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-03.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
```

> By strategically applying preload IDs to existing (X)HTML elements, we can use CSS’ background property to preload select images off-screen in the background. Then, as long as the paths to these images remains the same when they are referred to elsewhere in the web page, the browser will use the preloaded/cached images when rendering the page. Simple, effective, and no JavaScript required.

#### Method 2: Javascript Only

```
var images = new Array()
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image()
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
    }
}
preload(
    "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
    "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
    "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
)
```

***Source:** [Perishable Press](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)*

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
image = new Image(); 
image.src = "image.jpg";
image.onLoad = function(){
   alert("image ready");
}
```

Or with more images :

```
function all_images_preloaded(){
  alert("all images are ready to use");
}

var imgs = [
  "image1.jpg"
  , "image2.jpg"
  , "image3.jpg"
];

var count = imgs.length;
var count_loaded = 0;
for(i in imgs){
    image = new Image(); 
    image.src = "image.jpg";
    image.onLoad = function(){
       count_loaded++;
       if(count_loaded == count){
          all_images_preloaded();
       }
    }
}
```